# Split up a text of file using keyword to seperate blocks of text. PHP

Tags: php, parsing

I have a text file that is in this format:

```
[Term]
data
data
data

[Term]
data
data
data
data
data

[Term]
data
data
data
data
data
```

And would like to split the file by the word [Term], and get all the lines under it.
Any ideas which commands would suit this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `file_get_contents()` to load the whole file as string, then use `explode()` to make it into an array based on Term. You can then `explode()` each element using the newline character as separator to separate each line to its own (sub)element.

If you can change your structure to key-value pairs under each Term, you might also be able to use [parse-ini-file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) to parse it.

Comment: Thank you. Knew it was something simple, just couldnt suss it.